# SUM in MYSQL doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add sum of prices using ids in MYSQL. The code is like this: -

```
SELECT SUM(products.price) AS sum FROM products WHERE products.id in (32,33,34)
```

Let say the price of id 32 = $2, id 33 = $4 and id 34 = $5, the sum would be $11, which is correct. But the problem is when some of the ids are the same like this: -

```
SELECT SUM(products.price) AS sum FROM products WHERE products.id in (32,32,32)
```

Which is when user order 3 of the same product, the sum would be $2, and its supposed to be $6. How can I fix this?

Comment: why u need to pass the same id multiple times? and it doesn't matter even if the id's are duplicating it will only return the data once

Comment: Because the user want 3 of the same product. So I need to add the price of the product, which is in the case the price of id 32 is $2 which is in total I should get $6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to use `join`:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price) sum
FROM products p JOIN
     (SELECT 32 as id UNION ALL SELECT 32 UNION ALL SELECT 32
     ) i
     ON p.id = i.id;
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause in general and the `IN` comparison in particular cannot *increase* the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: @NoumanBhatti . . . Then obviously you would need to repeat the value in the subquery that many times.

Comment: why don't u multiply the count of products with the price ?

Comment: @NoumanBhatti . . . Because the `SUM()` is fewer operations and makes more sense to me.  The downvote is rude.

Comment: @NoumanBhatti I would not prefer (I'm not sure I actually can do that) to multiply when using MYSQL statement, instead I can just make 1 request to MYSQL and get the sum with just giving the multiple id. I think you shouldnt downvote the answer, bcs the answer is as what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(Total) AS Sum
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(Price) / COUNT(Id) As Total
    FROM products
    WHERE products.Id IN (32)
    GROUP BY products.Id
) AS table_price
```